# Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p=4n+1$, a prime number. Show that $(\frac{p-1}2)!$ is a root of $x^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

I have to prove the following part, but I can not. Please help me.

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p=4n+1$, a prime number.
Show that:

$((p-1)/2)!$ is a root of $x^2+1=0$ equation over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Have you considered that (p-1)!= -1 mod p.?

Answer (score 2):

We will use the following lemma.

**Lemma** (Wilson's Theorem): Let $p$ be a prime number. Then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 $ (mod $p$).

**Proof**: There are several proofs on the "Wilson's Theorem" Wikipedia page, and many available elsewhere online. I'd encourage you to try to prove it yourself before looking them up, though!

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Now observe that, for each $i$, we have (working in $\mathbb{Z}_p$)

$$
\frac{p-i}{2} = \frac{p-i}{2} - p = \frac{-p - i}{2} = -\frac{p+i}{2}
$$

It follows from this that

\begin{align}
(p-1)! &= (1)(2)\ldots(\frac{p-1}{2})(\frac{p+1}{2})\ldots(p-2)(p-1)
\\
&= (1)(2)\ldots(\frac{p-1}{2})(-\frac{p-1}{2})\ldots(-2)(-1)
\\
&= (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\Big((\frac{p-1}{2})!\Big)^2
\end{align}
Now, since $p = 4n+1$, we have that $(p-1)/2 = 2n$ is even, which means that $(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2} = 1$. Finally then, applying Wilson's Theorem, we obtain

$$
\Big((\frac{p-1}{2})!\Big)^2 = (p-1)! = -1
$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^2=b^2$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a=-b$ since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field. Consequently, every (nonzero) quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the square of a unique number in $\{1,2,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$. Thus, $\left((p-1)/2\right)!^2$ is the product of all the nonzero quadratic residues of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Recall also that the quadratic residues of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ form a group under multiplication modulo $p$. So, if $x$ is a quadratic residue, then so is its inverse $x^{-1}$ modulo $p$. Furthermore $x=x^{-1}$ if and only if $x^2=1$ which only occurs if $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Thus, every quadratic residue in the product $\left((p-1)/2\right)!^2$ is multiplied by its inverse and canceled out except for $1$ and $-1$ (note that $-1$ is a quadratic residue since $p\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 4)$). So, $\left((p-1)/2\right)!^2\equiv -1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, based on *Wilson's theorem*:

As $p>1$, $(p-1)!:=(4n)!\equiv -1\mod p$. Now we can split
$$(p-1)!=\underbrace{1\cdot2\cdots (2n-1)\cdot 2n}_{\bigl(\tfrac{p-1}2\bigr)!}\cdot(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(4n-1)4n $$ 
Now, for each $k\:$ s.t. $\:1\le k\le 2n$, observe that $\;2n+k\equiv -(2n+1-k)\bmod 4n+1$, so that
\begin{align}
(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(4n-2)(4n-1)4n&\equiv (-2n)\cdot-(2n-1)\cdots (-2)(-1) \\
&=(-1)^{2n} 2n \cdot (2n-1)\cdots  2\cdot 1= (2n)!,
\end{align}
and ultimately,
 $$-1\equiv (p-1)!\equiv \biggr[\Bigl(\frac{p-1}2\Bigr)!\biggr]^2 $$

Answer (score -1):

Wilsons Theorem says $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

And for any $k$ consecutive numbers, $m+1, m+2,.....,m+k$ we know that $k!$ divides $\prod (m+k)$.

So $\frac{p-1}{2}!$ will divide $1*2.....*\frac{p-1}2$ and $\frac {p-1}{2}!$ will divide $(\frac{p-1}2+1)*(\frac {p-1}2 +2)*.....*(p-1)$.

SO $(\frac{p-1}2)!^2$ will divide $1*2*...... *(p-1)=(p-1)!$.

So $(\frac{p-1}2)!^2 \equiv (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ ad $(\frac{p-1}2)!^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.